# How do i execute one event in php based on a probability for the event to happen

Tags: php, probability

**i want something like this:**

```
$chance = 40; //40%
if ( run the probability check script ) {
    echo "event happened"; //do the event
}
else {
   echo "event didn't happened";
}
```

what is the best solution to achieve something like that?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Depends on "the probability check script"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php):

```
if (rand(1,100)<=$chance)
```

This will return a number between 1 and 100, so that the probability of it being lower or equal to 40 is 40%.

Comment: What about a generic chance calculation? So $chance could = 0.1%, or 0.0001% or 1500%.

Answer (score 0):

Umm... Either I'm losing it or you mean you want the below...

```
$chance = 40;
if ($chance >= 40){
    echo "event happened"; //do the event
} else {
   echo "event didn't happened";
}
```

This assumes that the chance is equal to or is more than 40.

If you want chance to be randomly generated, then use something like `$chance = rand(0,100);` for a random number between 0 and 100 - then just use if statements to do the conditions.

At the end of the day it depends if your initial `$chance` is a fixed number or it is random or occurs as a result of a calculation.... unfortunately you haven't provided much insight...